# (IONIC - Angular) How can i show in html cards, only certain objects from a JSON that match certain criteria?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Im a noob in ionic/angular, and im trying to retrieve some data from a JSON, and show it in the HTML through cards ()

The JSON contains a lot of objects that are either "deTurno == true" or "deTurno == false"

so far i have this:

```
public data: any;
public test: any;
public testTwo: any;

constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {
  this.apiService.getFarmacias().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.data = data;
        
        for (const item of this.data) {
          if (item.deTurno == true) {
            
             // copy the item inside this.test

          } else {
             
             // copy the item inside this.testTwo

          }

        } 

      }
  );
}
```

what i want is to get every item inside the JSON that matches "deTurno == true", and put them inside test, so then i can use test to show those items in the HTML, like this:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let dataItem of test">
    <ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-subtitle>{{dataItem.direccion}}</ion-card-subtitle>
        <ion-card-title>{{dataItem.nombre}} (De turno hoy)</ion-card-title>
        <h5>Localidad: {{dataItem.localidad}}</h5>
        <h4>{{dataItem.telefono1}}</h4>
    </ion-card-header>
</ion-card>
```

I need to ONLY show those items that match "deTurno == true", and then do some stuff with the items that match "deTurno == false", otherwise i would show just every item from  "data"

Please help :(

Comment: What is the problem / error?  Your commented logic in your service to split them up is fine.  Are you getting an error because `test` is undefined?

Comment: the problem is that i dont know how to do what i have commented inside the FOR loop, to copy only the elements with "deTurno == true" from the JSON to a new array of objects, so then i can use that array instead. I've tryed something like this.test.push(item) but it says 'there's no "push" property of undefined'... i dont know how to do that

Comment: You are not defining test you are just saying it has a type of any.  I've added an answer on how to do that properly.

Comment: Omg thank you very much, i've been trying to solve this for like 10 hours!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue here is

```
public test: any;
```

You are not defining test, so you when you tried to push to it, its undefined.

```
public data: any[] = [];
public test: any[] = [];
public testTwo: any[] = [];

constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {
  this.apiService.getFarmacias().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.data = data;
        
        for (const item of this.data) {
          if (item.deTurno == true) {
            
             // copy the item inside this.test
             this.test.push(item);

          } else {
             
             // copy the item inside this.testTwo
             this.testTwo.push(item);


          }

        } 

      }
  );
}
```